# Access Payload in JWT token in Servicestack Request and Response Filter Attributes

Tags: c#, servicestack

I am programming a Service and ERP Software with an API that is Servicestack based.
In an Request Filter Attribute I want to check if the current user has permission to use a specific service by evaluating the ACL of the given service.
In a Response Filter Attribute I want to filter the result of the service.

Background: I have users in my company which have access to all customers and their data. Then I have users that belong to a customer and those users may only see the data of their company.
So at first I have to evaluate if a user has access to the requested service (CRUD) and if so I have to determine which of the resulting data the user may actually see in the UI.

I have populated my JWT like this:

```
{
  "iat": 1556223131,
  "exp": 1557432731,
  "preferred_username": "sa",
  "cwp_pid": "people/97-A",
  "cwp_bpid": "geschaeftspartners/481-A",
  "cwp_adm": "True",
  "cwp_su": "True"
}
```

In those Filter Attributes I need access my claims cwp_ to run my Reponse Filter and in the Request Filter I need access to cwp_pid (User ID).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using [ServiceStack's JWT Auth Provider](https://docs.servicestack.net/jwt-authprovider) you can retrieve the JWT Token in Request/Response filters using the `IRequest.GetJwtToken()` extension method, e.g:

```
GlobalRequestFilters.Add((req, res, dto) => {
    string jwt = req.GetJwtToken();

    var jwtProvider = AuthenticateService.GetRequiredJwtAuthProvider();

    IAuthSession session = jwtProvider.ConvertJwtToSession(req, jwt);                
    JsonObject jwtPayload = jwtProvider.GetVerifiedJwtPayload(req, jwt.Split('.'));
});
```

From there you can Convert the JWT token into a User Session or extract the JSON Payload as in a `JsonObject` dictionary as shown above.